# Fully exit julia scipt in interactive REPL

Tags: julia

I am starting a julia REPL in my project directory with `julia --project`.  Then I `include("scripts/main.jl")` in the REPL which runs some HTTP and WS servers.  If I hit ctrl-c to exit the script and return the REPL when I try to rerun the script it gives me errors that the server ports are already in use.  I think whats happening is the script isn't fully exiting.

Comment: Would a ctrl+d do what you're looking for? It would fully exit the repl.

Comment: I don't want to exit the repl.  I'm in it so my precompile time is once only.  I found includet from Revise.jl that helps with other things but not this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to think that it is possible to exit from an included script from a REPL session.

[Code inclusion](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/#Definitions) with `include("main.jl")` causes the contents of the file to be evaluated at the global scope. Afterwards the REPL is not able to distinguish if an expression came from an included script or from the REPL prompt.

If the script runs concurrent tasks chances are that Ctr-C is captured by one of them and the others continue to run, if a proper shutdown workflow is not implemented.

The following `main.jl` exposes the behavior probably similar to your case.

```
function task1()
    while true
        println("task1 alive")
        sleep(2)
    end
end

function task2()
    while true
        println("task2 alive")
        sleep(2)
    end
end

tsk1 = @async task1()
tsk2 = @async task2()

wait(tsk1)
```

```
julia> include("main.jl")
task1 alive
task2 alive
task1 alive
task2 alive
^C
ERROR: LoadError: InterruptException:
Stacktrace:
 [1] try_yieldto(undo::typeof(Base.ensure_rescheduled))
   @ Base ./task.jl:920
   ...
in expression starting at main.jl:18

julia> task1 alive
task1 alive
task1 alive
...
```